# Using variables in ruby erb variables

Tags: ruby, variables, erb

I have an erb file with a lot of these and I am trying to create a loop for them:

```
<% if @addhostgroup -%>
  <% @addhostgroup.each do |k, v| %>
    <%= k %> <%= v %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @addservicegroup -%>
  <% @addservicegroup.each do |k, v| %>
    <%= k %> <%= v %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
<% %w(addhostgroup addservicegroup).each do |action| %>
  <% if @action -%>
    <% @action.each do |k, v| %>
      <%= k %> <%= v %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Can somebody tell me how to use variables on erb variables names?

I was searching for a way without success.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show your recipe code also, we can't guess what you give to the template resource with only this few lines

Comment: It's usually a good idea to keep templates simple / dumb / logic-less. Have you considered merging the hashes outside the template and just passing a single hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: An easier way would be to make a normal array instead of a percent literal. `[@addhostgroup, @addservicegroup].each do |action|`.  Sometimes I over look the little things :)

You can use [instance_variable_get](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get) along with the array and iteration into `action` that you have setup.

Add a line immediately inside the each block with:
  `<% instance_var_value = instance_variable_get(:"@#{action}") %>`

You could also map the values into the array before iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that block variable `action` holds a string with the name of the action. You want to call `@variable` with dynamic name based on the name. You are searching for this piece of code:

```
instance_variable_get("@#{action}")
```

Comment: The block variable `action` will have precedence over the method `action` within the block, so that would not be a problem.

Comment: You're right, my wording fault... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @DonPaulie, thank you for your help. This is what I've looked for. I will accept Tom's answer because he just replied first.

Comment: @ice I was glad to help. I know, I only did not want to delete it just because another answer appeared before I completed mine :-D